Why does generalization error's integral integrate over both X and Y, not just X?
The formula for Generalization error, taken from Wikipedia:
$$
I[f]=\int _{X\times Y}V(f({\vec {x}}),y)\rho ({\vec {x}},y)d{\vec {x}}dy
$$
d2l.ai's version:
$$
 R[p, f] = E_{(\mathbf{x}, y) \sim P} [l(\mathbf{x}, y, f(\mathbf{x}))] =
   \int \int l(\mathbf{x}, y, f(\mathbf{x})) p(\mathbf{x}, y) \;d\mathbf{x} dy
$$
Compared to the discrete Empirical one that is simply the sum of all data points, why does the integral is also over Y, when X is enough to "cover" every cases.
(Forgive me for any incorrect uses of terms.)

Both risk formulations here are for supervised learning of a target label in the typical form of $\hat{y}=f(\mathbf{x})$, but they're not the usual empirical risk. Especially from your second version, it's an expectation thus it's the true risk assuming a known data (in the generative pair form $(\mathbf{x},y)$) generating full joint distribution $p(\mathbf{x},y)$. Therefore you have to integrate over both $\mathbf{x}$ and $y$.
